# Is it possible that one operator can run popup and modal?

Tags: python

I have an `invoke.popup()` I want a modal operator to be operated whenever I popup. I want 2 returning values from the invoke function. One is `return invoke.popup(self)` and the second is `return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}`. Is it possible to get both to work?

````
import bpy

class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom".upper()
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("object.custom_modal")
        
class CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "CUSTOM MODAL"
    bl_idname = "object.custom_modal"
    
    def modal(self,context,event):
        
        print("WORKING")

        return {"PASS_THROUGH"}
        
    def draw(self,context):
        self.layout.label(text="NEW")
        
    def invoke(self,context,event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"} and wm.invoke_popup(self)

classes = [CUSTOM_PT_PANEL,CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So unfortunately this is not possible. I guess you want to show something with `invoke_popup` and do some calculations in parallel.

This can be done using two operators and the first operator will call the second. In my case, I used the Draw-Operator to call the Modal-Operator. Also in my implementation the `CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR.close` variable is used to end the modal operation when the popup get closed.

If needed, you can transfer data between these two operators using a Property or PropertyGroup which is attached to the scene (e.g. `bpy.types.Scene = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="My Prop")`)

````
import bpy

class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom".upper()
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("object.draw_custom_modal")
        
class CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "CUSTOM MODAL"
    bl_idname = "object.custom_modal"
    bl_options = {"INTERNAL"}
    
    close = False
    
    def modal(self,context,event):
        
        if CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR.close == True:
            CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR.close = False
            return self.execute(context)
            
        if event.type == "ESC":
            return self.execute(context)
        
        if event.type != "TIMER":
            return {"PASS_THROUGH"}
        
        print("WORKING1")
        
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}
        
    def draw(self,context):
        self.layout.label(text="NEW")
        
    def invoke(self,context,event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        self.timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, window=context.window)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}
    
    def execute(self, context):
        print("CLOSE")
        context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self.timer)
        return {'FINISHED'}
        
class CUSTOM_OT_DRAWOPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "CUSTOM DRAW"
    bl_idname = "object.draw_custom_modal"
        
    def draw(self,context):
        self.layout.label(text="NEW")
        
    def invoke(self,context,event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.invoke_popup(self)
        bpy.ops.object.custom_modal("INVOKE_DEFAULT")
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}
    
    def execute(self, context):
        CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR.close = True
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def cancel(self, context):
        CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR.close = True
        

classes = [CUSTOM_PT_PANEL,CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR, CUSTOM_OT_DRAWOPERATOR]

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

```
````

Comment: Thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

use `invoke_props_dialog()` instead of `invoke_popup()`

```
import bpy


class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom".upper()
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("object.custom_modal")

 
class CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "CUSTOM MODAL"
    bl_idname = "object.custom_modal"
    
    
    def draw(self,context):
        self.layout.label(text="NEW")
        
    def invoke(self,context,event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
    
    def execute(self, context):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}
    
    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        print('RUNNING_MODAL')
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


classes = (
    CUSTOM_PT_PANEL,
    CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Another method

use event in `invoke()`

```
import bpy


class CUSTOM_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Custom"
    bl_idname = "CUSTOM_PT_PANEL"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Custom".upper()
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("object.custom_modal")

 
class CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "CUSTOM MODAL"
    bl_idname = "object.custom_modal"
    
    
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text="NEW")
        
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        if event.shift:
            context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
            return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

        return context.window_manager.invoke_popup(self)
    
    def execute(self, context):
        return {"FINISHED"}
    
    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        print('RUNNING_MODAL')

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


classes = (
    CUSTOM_PT_PANEL,
    CUSTOM_OT_OPERATOR
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Your examples are good but that's not what I'm looking for. Thanks